# How can I use python signals to send messages between independent processes?

Tags: python, ipc

I have two types of processes.

I want process `B` to wait for a message from process `A`. Once `A` sends the message, process `B` should process the message and wait again.

Also, I will have multiple instances of process `A` and process `B`. So, all the `B` processes should send the messages to all `A` processes.

I was looking at something like `signals`, but with a string attached to it.

What is the best way to do this?

I know I can create a `pipe` and keep reading the `pipe` in a `while`, but it seems inneficient. Also, won't it get removed from the `pipe` once read?

Note: None of the processes are subprocesses of each other.

Comment: How do processes `A` and `B` know of each other?

Comment: They don't. But I can get all the `A` processes to register their thread id`s somewhere, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is what I ended up doing at last...***

Made the producer process into a `module` and imported it into the consumer. Thus, both the processes can share variables.

Producer threads will keep producing and consumer threads will keep consuming. And I am using `condition` to synchronize the data, `threading.Condition()`.

Each Producer thread:

- Acquire `condition`
- Write data to a global variable
- Call `notifyAll()`
- Release `condition`

Each Consumer thread:

- Acquire `condition`
- Wait for the `condition`
- Read and process data in the global variable
- Wait for the `condition`...

This is just a high level view. In my case, I have different types of producer threads each producing different data and meant for a particular group of consumers. So, I have a `list of condition`.

[Reference on condition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects)

Comment: You say "process" in the question, but "thread" and "`threading.Condition()`" in the answer. Processes and threads have important technical differences. A single process can have multiple threads. They all share the process's address space, and so data in your shared module is accessible to both threads. Each process has its own address space, so `threading` won't help you share data between processes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose python bindings to ZeroMQ: http://www.zeromq.org/. pyzmq, perhaps: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq